# What --server do I use on meteor build <build-output-directory> --server=<host>:<port>?

Tags: android, meteor

I'm trying to build my app for Android and I believe it is not connecting to the proper server when I build it. I'm hosting it in AWS and it works in the browser from that site.

```
 meteor build <build-output-directory> --server=<host>:<port>
```

I've tried using the domain without the port, and the static IP address.

Comment: What version of Meteor are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.5 that i updated recently

Comment: Did you set `ROOT_URL`?

Comment: No, I haven't done that. It's not a problem with my web end of the project though.

Comment: Try to set it. See [this comment](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7849#issuecomment-250703165).

Comment: I've tried using Meteor.startup(function() {
  process.env.ROOT_URL = 'https://example.com';
}); to no avail. It is on https, does that make a difference?

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from setting an environment variable before building? It is possible that your server has the incorrect ROOT_URL, and then, when Cordova performs a hot code push to your app, the app's `__meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL` is set to `localhost:3000` or something similar, which causes it to fail to connect. And yes, the scheme (`https://`) is important.

Comment: I've got it working from a different comment on the thread you linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor appears to be having a problem assigning ROOT_URL in the build process when building for mobile. @MasterAM pointed me to [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7849#issuecomment-250703165) thread where I found the following work around:

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server http://whatever.com:3000
meteor build ../apk --server http://whatever.com:3000
```

The first line sets ROOT_URL references that remain active during the build process.

HTTPS does matter as well.